# ElectronJS - ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when using import

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to learn ElectronJS. I am OK with "Vanilla" JavaScript but when it comes to Node I am clueless. Everything works when I use the  tag in my html and run all the code from that .js code. However I am now trying to import a class and get an `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error when I launch the program. This is the basic code explaining where my problem happens.

Vector3 Class:

```
export class Vector3{
    constructor(x, y, z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Test.js file used in <script type="module" src="Test.js>

```
import {Vector3} from "./mathf/Vector3"

function main(){
    let vec = new Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    console.log(vec.x);
}

window.onload = main;
```

I even had a look at RequireJS but I seemed to get more errors (due to me not knowing what is going on)

I also tried the `const {Vector3} = require('./mathf/Vector3');` And used `module.exports.Vector3 = Vector3` in my Vector3.js file. But `require` is not defined seeing as it's running the JS on the client side.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction or tell me how I would be able to import the Vector3 class into my test.js code?

```
.
+-- mathf
|   +-- Vector3.js
+-- node_modules
|   +-- ...
+-- main.html
+-- main.js
+-- package-lock.json
+-- package.json
+-- Test.js
```

[image: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]

<=========== SOLUTION ===========>

The solution was to simply add the following when creating the `BrowserWindow()`

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences:{
            contextIsolation: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            nodeIntegrationInWorker: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is your directory tree structure?

Comment: @vanowm I have updated my question to include the tree structure.